# Populate DataGridView Columns only from DataTable Dynamically

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am writing a stock system and the current interface I am working on allows users to add items to the database. There is a different table for each item type.

What I can currently do, is populate the `DataGridView` with the entire table and its content, which is obviously not ideal.

What I would like to happen is, a user selects the type of item they want to add to the database from a `ComboBox` this then populates a `DataGridView` with the columns from the corresponding table for that item, but not the content. The user can then add a new row and populate the fields.

here is the code behind the `ComboBox`, this also allows the user to select the sub type from a second `ComboBox`.

```
        var row = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        comboBox2.Items.Clear();
        comboBox2.Text = "";

        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "ARRAYS")
        {
            var nameDT = (from names in ARRAYS.AsEnumerable()
                          where names.Field<string>("Array Type") != null
                          select names.Array_Type);

            var cleanList = nameDT.Distinct().ToArray();
            foreach (var item in cleanList)
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "BATT_CHARGER")
        {
            var nameDT = (from names in BATT_CHARGER.AsEnumerable()
                          where names.Field<string>("BATT_SIZE") != null
                          select names.BATT_SIZE);

            var cleanList = nameDT.Distinct().ToArray();
            foreach (var item in cleanList)
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "BUFFERBOX")
        {
            var nameDT = (from names in BUFFERBOX.AsEnumerable()
                          where names.Field<string>("BufferBox Type") != null
                          select names.BufferBox_Type);

            var cleanList = nameDT.Distinct().ToArray();
            foreach (var item in cleanList)
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

How can I set the `DataGridView` columns to the same as the tables they will be saving into, without filling it with all the row data?

ARRAYS

BUFFERBOX

BATT_CHARGER

are all table names, and Array Type, BATT_SIZE and BufferBox Type are column names.

Comment: Are you setting the autogeneratecolumns = true? You could just build the column and not fill the table until you want.

Comment: I have no settings on the dgv other than what are default. How would i just build the columns?

Comment: @JamesMorrish can you post the code which populates `DataGridView` currently?

Comment: It's just in `if` statements and the DataSource changes depending on the table selected. 

dataGridView1.DataSource = BUFFERBOX;

Comment: I usually fill DGV from a data table like : datagridview1.DataSource = dt.  Then you DGV is dynamic base on the query you use to fill the table.

Comment: I strongly recommend `DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False` (as opposed to above). First (but not last), you want to put proper header text to the columns, perhaps aligning numbers to the right, setting units, etc. I would create a simple `DataTable` (in DB, or even hardcoded) with the list of *ColumnNames*, *ColumnHeaderText* and *TableType* (=which type product), you can have also enum columns like alignment, suffix (measuring unit), etc. Then create columns dynamically, looping this `DataTable`, filtered with `.Select("TableType =" + <...>)`, before you load `DataGridView1` content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this which works perfectly.

```
 if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "USB_RS232")
        {
            var nameDT = (from names in USB_RS232.AsEnumerable()
                          where names.Field<string>("MODEL") != null
                          select names.MODEL);

            datatable = USB_RS232;

            var cleanList = nameDT.Distinct().ToArray();
            foreach (var item in cleanList)
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }


        dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
        foreach (DataColumn item in datatable.Columns)
        {
            var colname = item.ColumnName.ToString();
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colname, colname);
        }
```

The `dataTable` is selected when you pick from the `comboBox` then i just loop throught he column names in the `dataTable` and add them to the DGV.